# Excel VBA shorten code to copy values from one range to another

Tags: excel, vba

I've been given an Excel workbook with the following code and would like to know how to shorten it to make it easier to manage.  The code repeatedly copies values from certain cells in one named range to certain cells in another named range and also copies font and fill color.  The code is longer than this (following the same pattern with the named ranges incrementing by 1) so I'm sure there is a much better way of writing it.

```
Private Sub Copy_Jobs()

Worksheets("Sales").Range("Week1")(1).Cells.Value = Worksheets("Tasks").Range("Job1")(1).Cells.Value
Worksheets("Sales").Range("Week1")(2).Cells.Value = Worksheets("Tasks").Range("Job1")(2).Cells.Value
Worksheets("Sales").Range("Week1")(3).Cells.Value = Worksheets("Tasks").Range("Job1")(3).Cells.Value
Worksheets("Sales").Range("Week1")(4).Cells.Value = Worksheets("Tasks").Range("Job1")(5).Cells.Value
Worksheets("Sales").Range("Week1").Font.Color = Worksheets("Tasks").Range("Job1").Font.Color
Worksheets("Sales").Range("Week1").Interior.Color = Worksheets("Tasks").Range("Job1").Interior.Color

Worksheets("Sales").Range("Week2")(1).Cells.Value = Worksheets("Tasks").Range("Job2")(1).Cells.Value
Worksheets("Sales").Range("Week2")(2).Cells.Value = Worksheets("Tasks").Range("Job2")(2).Cells.Value
Worksheets("Sales").Range("Week2")(3).Cells.Value = Worksheets("Tasks").Range("Job2")(3).Cells.Value
Worksheets("Sales").Range("Week2")(4).Cells.Value = Worksheets("Tasks").Range("Job2")(5).Cells.Value
Worksheets("Sales").Range("Week2").Font.Color = Worksheets("Tasks").Range("Job2").Font.Color
Worksheets("Sales").Range("Week2").Interior.Color = Worksheets("Tasks").Range("Job2").Interior.Color

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Splitting out the common code into a separate sub...

```
Private Sub Copy_Jobs()
    'either like this...
    CopyAndFormat Worksheets("Sales").Range("Week1"), _
                  Worksheets("Tasks").Range("Job1")

    CopyAndFormat Worksheets("Sales").Range("Week2"), _
                  Worksheets("Tasks").Range("Job2")

    '...or in a loop
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 to 5
        CopyAndFormat Worksheets("Sales").Range("Week" & i), _
                      Worksheets("Tasks").Range("Job" & i)
    Next i

End Sub

Sub CopyAndFormat(w as Range, j As Range)
    w(1).Cells.Value = j(1).Cells.Value
    w(2).Cells.Value = j(2).Cells.Value
    w(3).Cells.Value = j(3).Cells.Value
    w(4).Cells.Value = j(5).Cells.Value
    w.Font.Color = j.Font.Color
    w.Interior.Color = j.Interior.Color
End Sub
```

Note that copying font and interior colors only really works if the ranges are formatted consistently.

Comment: Many thanks Tim, it works great and will really help me to tidy up other similar code in the workbook.